# R magick function equivalent to IM6 convert -unsharp

Tags: r, imagemagick

I wonder what is the function in the R `magick` package that corresponds to the command line:

```sh
convert in.png -unsharp 10x4+1+0 out.png
```

Do I need to run the shell script directly using `system()`?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe its the `image_blur` see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html#Filters_and_effects ?

Comment: @Jonas Thanks. I've tried that, but it turned out that `image_blue` blurs the image, while `convert -unsharp` sharpens the image (strange naming).

Comment: *"Unsharp masking"* can be achieved by blurring a copy of the original image and subtracting a proportion of that from the original. Essentially the blurred copy represents low frequencies (slowly changing features) and by removing low frequencies you are left with proportionally more higher frequencies, i.e. edges.

Comment: Better explanation... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsharp_masking

Comment: The name makes perfect sense now. Thanks.